# need to modify this jquery pop menu script to work with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this script from: http://pop.seaofclouds.com/

The problem is if you call the script multiple times it causes a cascading effect of a pop-out within a pop-out for as many times as you call the script.

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent it from executing when the popout has already been set. Here's the script:

```
//
//  pop! for jQuery
//  v0.2 requires jQuery v1.2 or later
//  
//  Licensed under the MIT:
//  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
//  
//  Copyright 2007,2008 SEAOFCLOUDS [http://seaofclouds.com]
//

(function($) {

  $.pop = function(options){

    // inject html wrapper
    function initpops (){
      $(".pop").each(function() {
        var pop_classes = $(this).attr("class");        
        if ( $(this).find('.pop_menu').length) {        
            // do nothing       
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("pop_menu");       
            $(this).wrap("<div class='"+pop_classes+"'></div>");
            $(".pop_menu").attr("class", "pop_menu");
            $(this).before(" \
            <div class='pop_toggle'></div> \
            ");       
        }       

      });
    }
    initpops();

    // assign reverse z-indexes to each pop
    var totalpops = $(".pop").length + 100;
    $(".pop").each(function(i) {
    var popzindex = totalpops - i;
    $(this).css({ zIndex: popzindex });
    });

    // close pops if user clicks outside of pop
    activePop = null;
    function closeInactivePop() {
      $(".pop").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') && i!=activePop) {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
          }
      });
      return false;
    }
    $(".pop").mouseover(function() { activePop = $(".pop").index(this); });
    $(".pop").mouseout(function() { activePop = null; });

    $("body").on("click", ".pop", function(){       
     closeInactivePop();
    });
    // toggle that pop
    $("body").on("click", ".pop_toggle", function(){
      $(this).parent(".pop").toggleClass("active");
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

now when i load this script on an ajax call the new pop-out menus work but the old ones do not react to the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mess with the plugin. It works exactly like it should.
Better show us how you call this on elements that you already have.

Also I don't like this plugin. Better use something from [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)
You can do such thing in much easier way.

[edit]
I tried your first code (the plugin) and it works correctly for me.

[edit]
OK. I get it. You call $.pop(); multiple times. You shouldn't! Calling $.pop(); will pin up the drop down menu to all elements that has class="pop". This is the reason why you have such funny stack.
Just use $.pop(); once.
Plugin doesn't give ability to connect NEW elements that was dynamically created on the page.

Comment: The thing is I am using ajax to call new .pop elements so I need to then trigger the pop event to activate those new elements. I understand the plug-in was not designed for that. That's why I need to modify the code accordingly so that it does.

Comment: Don't modify it. Not worth it. Better write something much easier what you can pin up to specified element.

You can also add one more class like .pop_ready so after one is created you change class .pop to .pop_ready
This way after next init they will not be rendered again.
It's not much work :)

Answer (score 0):

Removed pop from ajax call and just called this on success:

```
                $(".pop").each(function() {
                var pop_classes = $(this).attr("class");        
                if ( $(this).find('.pop_menu').length) {        
                // do nothing       
                } else {
                $(this).addClass("pop_menu");       
                $(this).wrap("<div class='"+pop_classes+"'></div>");
                $(".pop_menu").attr("class", "pop_menu");
                $(this).before(" \
                <div class='pop_toggle'></div> \
                ");       
                }                               
                });     
                // assign reverse z-indexes to each pop
                var totalpops = $(".pop").length + 100;
                $(".pop").each(function(i) {
                var popzindex = totalpops - i;
                $(this).css({ zIndex: popzindex });
                });     
                // close pops if user clicks outside of pop
                activePop = null;
                function closeInactivePop() {
                  $(".pop").each(function (i) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('active') && i!=activePop) {
                      $(this).removeClass('active');
                      }
                  });
                  return false;
                }
                $(".pop").mouseover(function() { activePop = $(".pop").index(this); });
                $(".pop").mouseout(function() { activePop = null; });
```